# Editor fails to parse Python file in Java project

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 with the latest Python plugin.

I have a simple (one-module) Java project with a Python script inside it. The Project SDK is set as Java 1.8, and in Project Settings -> Facets, I have "Python", and "Python Interpreter" is set as Python 3.8.

The Python file is runnable from the Terminal window and from IDEA's Run menu, but the editor shows a red squiggle under "os" in the line `import os`. I can use the editor to ctrl-click into a function defined elsewhere in that file, but can't go to a Python system function.

If I set the project SDK to be Python, then everything works OK in the editor when editing the Python script, but now I can't edit Java files (things like `String` are unrecognised).

Is there a way to get IDEA to recognise Java and Python files at the same time?

Comment: have you tried using language injections feature? https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/06/language-injections-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: @JahanBalasubramaniam thanks, but that doesn't seem to help. Language injections are about syntax in a non-Java language that is embedded in a Java String. This does not represent my use case.

Comment: Try to remove the interpreter from Project Structure -> "SDKs" and "Global Libraries" and read it back for the facet.